# How to make Spring Service check authentification?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have **2 Services**, the **1st** one is for establishing the connection (a simple login in the browser Port 8080).
The **2nd** one is the main page (Port 8082)

The login is successful and redirects the user to the **2nd** Service's page (Port 8082), but when I logout from the **1st** service (/logout), the user can still access the page on the **2nd** Service's page (Port 8082)

How can I make the **2nd** service's page ask for a re authentification ?

P.s: the authentification is via LDAP

Comment: Manually triggering `HttpServletRequest'`s `logout` function?

Comment: yes, manually in the browser.